# Example of probability space s.t. $p(A)=0$, $p(B)=1$ and $A≠∅, B≠Ω$

Tags: probability-theory

I had a question of finding a probabilty space $(Ω,β,p)$ s.t. $A,B∈β$ ,  $p(A)=0$, $p(B)=1$ and $A≠∅, B≠Ω$.

This is what I thought for solution: I thought about the problem of throwing a dice with $3$ faces- $1$, $2$, $3$. The probability to get $1$ is $0.4$, the probability to get $2$ is $0.6$ and the probability to get $3$ is $0$ (sort of unfair dice).
So I can take the following probability space: $Ω=\{1,2,3\}$, $β=2^Ω$, and 
 $p:β\to [0,1]$ will be defined according to the probabilities I wrote above. We can see that this is  a valid probability space, and can take $A=\{3\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$ to get what we want.

However, something in my solution doesn't seem right to me. For example, I suspect that if $p(3)=0$, then $3$ should not be included in $Ω$.
Is my solution correct?

Comment: Try choosing a real number at random, where $A$ is choosing a rational number and $B$ an irrational one.

Comment: Darth, I'm more interested to check if my solution is correct than finding another solution (I already know another solution for this problem). I just think that maybe I have wrong assumptions in my solution

Comment: If the dice does have a $3$ then it is technically possible to get one (even if the probability is $0$). I'd say your solution is correct. What you have described are what are known as "almost impossible" and "almost sure" events, respectively.

Comment: The dice itself could be an infinitely thin coin where $1$ represents heads, $2$ representants tails and $3$ represents that it lands on it's side.

Comment: Probably working too much. Why not consider the interval $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, if I suspect that if $P(3) = 0$, then $3$ should not be included in $\Omega$.

Mathematically speaking, there is nothing *wrong* with including $3$ in your $\Omega$.  In a certain setting, it may be sensible to exclude it, but there are many reasons to leave events of probability zero in your space.

Here's another solution along these lines: we flip a fair coin and define
$$
\Omega = \{H,T,Z\} 
$$
$H$ denotes the event in which the coin lands "heads".  $T$ denotes the event in which the coin lands "tails".  $Z$ denotes the event in which the coin hovers midair, becomes sentient, learns to speak, and teaches you probability.  We may suppose that $Z$ has probability zero.

---

As for *why* one might include such an event in $\Omega$, one reason is for convenient comparisons of distributions.  For example, we might have two random variables $X,Y$ with
$$
P(X = 1) = P(X=2) = 1/2; \quad P(X = 3) = 0\\
P(Y = 1) = 0; \quad P(Y = 2) = P(Y = 3) = 0
$$
Rather than take $\Omega_X = \{1,2\}$ and $\Omega_Y = \{2,3\}$, it is often convenient to use a common sample space such as $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$ or even $\Omega = \Bbb N$.

Comment: It'd be nice if you included an example where it is important to leave events of probability $0$ (any uncountable sample space works).

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about that, the event "3" that I defined in my solution, and the event Z that you defined in your solution are impossible events. And as far as I know, in a finite sample space the impossible event is considered as the empty set. Isn't it so?

Comment: @John as I've said, not necessarily.